# Coercible with GHC 7.10

Tags: haskell, ghc

The following code works in GHC 7.8.4:

```
import Data.Coerce
coerceNewtype :: (Coercible (o r) (n m' r)) => [o r] -> [n m' r]
coerceNewtype = coerce
```

but in 7.10 I get the error:

```
Couldn't match representation of type ‘n m' r’ with that of ‘o r’
arising from trying to show that the representations of
  ‘[o r]’ and
  ‘[n m' r]’ are the same
Relevant role signatures: type role [] representational
```

I'm not quite sure where the magic happens in `Data.Coerce`, but given that `coerce` has the signature `(Coercible a b) => a -> b`, I think the function above should still compile in 7.10. Any ideas why the behavior is different, or how I can get use coercible with polymorphic types in 7.10?

Comment: Change the type signature to `(Coercible a b, a ~ (o r), b ~ (n m' r)) => [o r] -> [n m' r]` and the error goes away. This is on ghc-7.10.1. This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Hrm, it seemed too simple to be a bug. Reported [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10428)

Comment: Could one of you turn these comments into an answer so the question doesn't show up as unanswered? @user2407038

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code.

The error is due to a [bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10494) in the type-checker. The issue tracker says this will be fixed in GHC 7.11.

---

<sup>Posting simply to provide an answer, since the original author doesn't post one. Feel free to add details if you wish (and are able).</sup>